# O que causa o erro [could not bind to "tcp://127.0.0.1:8843". Cannot assign request adress]?

Tags: php

Vamos lá. Eu estou tenho um script em PHP que serve para criar um servidor websocket para minha aplicação. Estou utilizando o websocket do HTML5.

Para criar o servidor, estou utilizando a biblioteca Ratchet encontrada no site [socketo.me](http://socketo.me/).

Rodo esse código abaixo a partir da linha de comando:

```
 list ($host, $port) = $argv + ['localhost', 9000];

 $app = new Ratchet\App($host, $port, '0.0.0.0');

 $app->route('/chat', new Chat, array('*'));

 $app->route('/notificador', new Notificador, array('*'));

 $app->run();
```

Tudo estava funcionando perfeitamente. De repente, esse serviço parou de funcionar. Tentei utilizar o mesmo comando para iniciá-lo novamente, mas sempre é apresentada a seguinte mensagem:

> Could not bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:8843: Cannot assign requested address

É importante explicar que eu não utilizo a porta 8843 para executar esse script, uso a porta 9000. Porém a biblioteca Ratchet utiliza.

Um trecho do  construtor da classe `Ratchet\App`:

```
    if (80 == $port) {
        $flashSock->listen(843, '0.0.0.0');
    } else {
        $flashSock->listen(8843);
    }
```

Por sua vez o método `listen` tem o seguinte trecho:

```
   $this->master = @stream_socket_server("tcp://$host:$port", $errno, $errstr);
    if (false === $this->master) {
        $message = "Could not bind to tcp://$host:$port: $errstr";
        throw new ConnectionException($message, $errno);
    }
```

O estranho é que já liguei para o pessoal da `dialhost`, onde temos a hospedagem e foi verificado que **não existe** nenhum serviço rodando nessa porta. Então não se trataria de um erro do tipo "a porta já está ocupada".

## O que já tentei fazer?

- Pedi para reiniciar o servidor (Linux).
- O funcionário da dialhost disse que a porta não está ocupada. Ele alegou ter verificado isso via comando `telnet`.
- Já executei o comando `fuser -k 8843/tcp` para tentar matar algum processo que estivesse ocupando nessa porta.
- Já fiz o processo utilizando uma porta em uso (de propósito), pra ver se a mensagem retornada seria diferente, e retornou diferente:

> Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0:9001: Address already in use

... porém nada resolveu!

E agora, quem poderá me ajudar?

Comment: [Ele!](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YWPz46T1Ln0/U3EobzrSmDI/AAAAAAAAGTI/8Lr_p55wC6w/s1600/Chapolin+1.gif)

Comment: Será que não tem nenhum firewall ou proxy bloqueando o tráfego dessa porta?

Comment: @Bacco acho que ele usou a buzina paralisadora nessa porta. Pede para ele apertá-la duas vezes pra desfazer o efeito :)

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque [o Wallace pediu](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30595966#30595966).

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. O funcionário da hospedagem disse que o problema era que a interface loopback não estava rodando.

O interessante é que, como desmontrado na pergunta, o trecho que utiliza a função `listen` demonstra que, se não passar o segundo parâmetro, seria adicionada o 127.0.0.1.

A função `stream_socket_server` só funcionava com `0.0.0.0`.

Então, depois que ele iniciou o tal do loopback, tudo voltou a funcionar perfeitamente, como antes.