# O que é uma interface loopback?

Tags: socket, redes

Estava passando por problemas de conexão socket  no meu servidor:

[O que causa o erro [could not bind to "tcp://127.0.0.1:8843". Cannot assign request adress]?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107854/o-que-causa-o-erro-could-not-bind-to-tcp-127-0-0-18843-cannot-assign-requ/107859#107859)

Consegui resolver o problema. O técnico me disse que o problema era que "a interface loopback estava parada e tinha que ser iniciada".

Como já disse, sou péssimo em termos técnicos.

Então, gostaria de entender o que é uma interface loopback.

E por que, ao parar de rodar, fez com que todo código que utilizasse conexões sockets com `127.0.0.1` parasse de funcionar, sendo aceito somente `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Quem garante que o cara não te enrolou? :P

Comment: @rray não me coloque em dúvidas, amigo. Na verdade, depois que falei com ele: "Só está funcionando com 0.0.0.0, com localhost não funciona?", ele fez a expressão: "Nossa, seu loopback não tá rodando". E aí funcionou :D

Answer (score 3):

A interface loopback é uma interface virtual de rede utilizada basicamente com dois propósitos:

- Diagnóstico;
- Para desenvolvimento e teste de sistemas que necessitem de uma interface de rede com um IP (Webservers, etc).

Em um sistema Linux, digite ifconfig para verificar a sua interface loopback:

```
ifconfig


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:353933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:353933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:584828381 (584.8 MB)  TX bytes:584828381 (584.8 MB)
```

Por ser uma interface de rede é possível pará-la:

```
sudo ifconfig lo down
```

Assim como levantá-la:

```
sudo ifconfig lo up
```

A parte de diagnóstico pode servir, por exemplo, pra verificar se sua máquina está com o servidor ssh ativo. Tente isso:

```
ssh user@localhost
```

Se a máquina em questão estiver com um servidor SSH escutando na porta 22, então a própria máquina será acessada a partir dela mesmo via SSH (veja o loopback acontecendo). :-)

Já na parte de desenvolvimento de sistemas, a interface loopback é amplamente utilizada quando deseja-se desenvolver e rodar o servidor (web, tcp, etc) na própria máquina. Exemplo de um endereço quando se está desenvolvendo Java + Tomcat: http://localhost:8080/App ou http://127.0.0.1:8080/App

É interessante notar que o range de IPs associado a essa interface é o `127.0.0.0/8`. Portanto, você pode pingar qualquer um dos endereços que vão de `127.0.0.1` até `127.255.255.254` que essa interface responderá. Porém, o mais famoso é o primeiro, `127.0.0.1`. É geralmente nesse IP que está associado o famoso *hostname* `localhost`.