# Por que o localhost não entra na internet?

Tags: ip, localhost

Porque não podemos usar o IP 127.0.0.1 na internet? Porque `localhost` retorna a mesma máquina? Porque o `localhost` é bloqueado? A onde posso encontrar informações relevantes?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Sua pergunta não está clara

Comment: Porque não podemos usar o ip 127.0.0.1 na internet? Porque localhost retorna a mesma máquina? Porque o localhost é bloqueado? A onde posso encontrar informações relevantes?

Comment: Agora entendi, dá uma olhada [nisso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) e [nisso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Comment: Resumindo, esses endereços apontam para a máquina atual, por isso não dá para acessar na internet diretamente por `localhost`, essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107928/53279) explica um pouco também

Comment: Para evitar que não consiga editar suas perguntas, sugiro que crie uma conta definitiva no site e solicite um merge com a conta que criou esta pergunta, atraves deste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Já solicitei o merge das contas

Comment: A pergunta foi bem fechada porque originalmente ela era outra bem diferente sito, apenas o assunto era o mesmo. Acho até que deve reverter para a original e ter uma nova pergunta com este assunto.

Comment: @castro-ale A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6):

Por especificação todo IP com classe A 127 é reservado para rede interna, portanto é possível usar mais de 16 milhões de endereços internamente.

Claro que isto vale para IPv4. Em IPv6 muda um pouco.

Redes baseadas em IP precisam se comunicar através desses endereços separados em blocos, ou classes como são chamados formalmente. Isto facilita o roteamento dos pacotes de dados e separação em sub-redes. O IP é o endereço onde deve ir.

Se não tivesse um bloco reservado todas as máquinas teriam que usar IPs públicos controlados por alguma entidade e não haveria separação alguma. Hoje pode começar parecer estranho para alguns, mas nem sempre queremos todas máquinas comunicando na internet diretamente. Tendo este bloco isolado também permite que esses números sejam usados repetidas vezes, já que cada rede interna é separada das outras.

Se convencionou que o 127.0.0.1 seria um endereço reservado para a própria máquina se auto referenciar. Então é o mesmo processo, só que desta vez basta ter um IP. Sempre que alguma aplicação usar este endereço em uma máquina, não sai de dentro desta máquina. Se não pode sair, não pode entrar.

Isto é chamado [*loopback*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback).

- [RFC sobre os números da internet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1166)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)