# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] XML-RPC python

Tags: python

Estou tentando conectar em um server usando o python 3 com xml-rpc, mas está aparecendo um erro toda vez que tento conectar: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Esse é o meu código do servidor: (OBS: Estou apenas fazendo testes bobos.)

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def void():
  x = 1000
  i = 0
  while i < x:
      i = i+1
  return True

def main():
  print("This is a server!")
  server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8080))
  server.register_function(void)
  server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Esse é o meu código cliente:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import time

def main():
  print("This is a client!")
  client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000")
  client.void()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  start = time.time()
  main()
  total_time = ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start))
  print("Time: " + str(total_time))
```

Quando eu executo o xml-rpc no mesmo computador (terminal diferente) ele funciona normal, mas quando tento em dois computadores diferentes, ele da esse erro.

Comment: **Juny**, tal como o nome sugere (StackOverflow **em português**), o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Nossa, confundi total hahaha. Já traduzi, obrigado pelo feedback!

Comment: Já tentou em vez de `http://localhost` você colocar o IP do computador na rede local ? Ex: `http://192.168.0.30:8000` ?

Comment: Yeeeeah! Funcionou! Valeu @NoobSaibot

Comment: @NoobSaibot melhor botar o comentário como uma resposta pra que outros que tenham o mesmo problema achem a solução pelo google (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta obtendo o erro:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

porque esta tentando acessar uma *Interface Loopback*, a interface loopback é uma interface virtual de rede utilizada basicamente com dois propósitos:

- Diagnóstico;
- Para desenvolvimento e teste de sistemas que necessitem de uma interface de rede com um IP (Webservers, etc).

Para acessar em sua rede local, você precisa localizar o endereço de IP local do seu servidor, fazendo [uma pesquisa no *Google*](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=localizar%20o%20endere%C3%A7o%20IP%20interno%20de%20seu%20computador), você encontra varios tutoriais ensinando a encontrar o endereço. Mas por padrão, os roteadores e ou moldem utilizam *192.168.0.x* ou *192.168.1.x*.

#### Referências

- [Localizar o endereço IP interno de seu computador - Pesquisa no Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=localizar%20o%20endere%C3%A7o%20IP%20interno%20de%20seu%20computador)
- [O que é uma interface loopback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107866)